# Moments of equally weighted mixture of two bivariate normal

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

Suppose I have two bivariate random vectors $\tilde{W}, \bar{W}$ distributed as follows
$$
\bar{W}\sim \mathcal{N}(\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \rho_{\bar{W}}\\
\rho_{\bar{W}} & 1
\end{pmatrix})
$$
$$
\tilde{W}\sim \mathcal{N}(\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \rho_{\tilde{W}}\\
\rho_{\tilde{W}} & 1
\end{pmatrix})
$$
with $\bar{\rho}_W, \tilde{\rho}_w \in [-1,1]$.
Take a bivariate random vector $W$ distributed as $\frac{1}{2}\bar{W}+\frac{1}{2}\tilde{W}$ (equally weighted mixture).

Could you help me to derive $E(W)$ and $Var(W)$? I found some directions for univariate normal (e.g., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16608/what-is-the-variance-of-the-weighted-mixture-of-two-gaussians)) but I couldn't find the analysis for the multivariate case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the expectation of $W=0.5 \tilde{W} + 0.5\overline{W}$, you should use the linearity property of expectations ($\mathbb{E}(X+Y)=\mathbb{E}(X)+\mathbb{E}(Y)$) and to calculate the variance you essentially need to calculate
$$ \mathbb{E}(WW') = \mathbb{E}((0.5 \tilde{W} + 0.5 \overline{W})(0.5 \tilde{W} + 0.5 \overline{W})') = 0.25\mathbb{E}\left( \tilde{W} \tilde{W}' + \tilde{W} \overline{W}' + \overline{W} \tilde{W}' + \overline{W}\overline{W}'\right)$$
Here, you should use again the linearity property of the expectation and that $\tilde{W}$ and $\overline{W}$ are independent (thus the expectation of the product, is the product of the expectations). Then invoke the assumptions, i.e., you know for example $\mathbb{E}(\tilde{W}\tilde{W}') = \text{Var}(\tilde{W}) + \mathbb{E}(\tilde{W})\mathbb{E}(\tilde{W}')$.

If you work this out, you will get the result. If you need more information on the matter, I can provide you with it. I hope this helps!

edit: changed the notation to make it clearer.

Comment: When $\bar{W}$ and $\tilde{W}$ are independent I get $\mu=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $Var(W)=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} &\frac{\rho_{\bar{W}}+\rho_{\tilde{W}}}{4}\\
\frac{\rho_{\bar{W}}+\rho_{\tilde{W}}}{4} & \frac{\sigma^2_{\bar{W}}+\sigma^2_{\tilde{W}}}{4}
\end{pmatrix}$. Can you confirm?

Comment: What if $\bar{W}$ and $\tilde{W}$ are not independent? We can't derive the moments of $W$, correct (unless we specify the joint distribution of $\bar{W}$ and $\tilde{W}$)?

Comment: Almost correct, (I don't know what your $\sigma_W$ is though), but it should be $ \mu =\left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ -1 \end{array}\right) $ and the element of $\text{Var}(W)$ at the bottom right should be equal to $0.5$.

If the two variables $\tilde{W}$ and $\overline{W}$ are depedent, you have to know something about the dependence structure between the two to make a certain calculation. For example if $\tilde{W}=-\overline{W}$, then $W=0$ and the whole thing changes.

Comment: Thanks! I think the mean should be $0,0$ (you see that the signs are flipped for the two means)?

Comment: O, yes, you are right. You had the mean correct, I didn't notice the flipped signs.